# XAML DataTemplate Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I am trying to make an application for WP8, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how data binding works. I have tried example after example, which seem like they are doing pretty much exactly the same as me, but nothing seems to work. Basically the profile class contains the name of a profile and an icon. I want to display a list of these profiles on the screen, with the name to the right of the icon.

When I run the project in the WP8 phone emulator, nothing shows up at all. If i change the properties of the elements in the DataTemplate (namely Source and Text) to absolute strings, it works fine.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ..>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ProfileListTemplate">
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProfileName}" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="36"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ProfilesList" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Height="535" Margin="10,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProfileListTemplate}"/>
</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Profiles
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<Profile> ProfilesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
            ProfilesCollection.Add(new Profile("Nighttime"));
            ProfilesCollection.Add(new Profile("Work"));
            ProfilesCollection.Add(new Profile("Home"));
            ProfilesList.ItemsSource = ProfilesCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

"Profile" Class:

```
namespace Profiles
{
    class Profile
    {
        public string ProfileName = "";
        public string ImageSource = "/Resources/Delete.png";

        public Profile(string name)
        {
            ProfileName = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `ProfileName` and `ImageSource` from fields to properties.

```
class Profile
{
    private const string DefaultImageSource = "/Resources/Delete.png";

    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource {get; set; }

    public Profile(string name)
    {
        ProfileName = name;
        ImageSource = DefaultImageSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Profile class to be properties, as in the following...

```
public class Profile
{
    string profileName = "";
    string imageSource = "/Resources/Delete.png";

    public string ProfileName
    {
        get
        {
            return profileName;
        }
        set
        {
            profileName = value;
        }
    }
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return imageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            imageSource = value;
        }
    }

    public Profile(string name)
    {
        ProfileName = name;
    }
}
```

As your logic gets more involved, it is then relatively trivial to add further behaviour, and also implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you need to track changes within a single object.